# Long GET requests are repeating in AngularJS & Node App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

So I have an AngularJS(1) app which essentially runs a server side script when a user clicks a button.

client side controller Angular calls this method when a button is clicked:

```
   $scope.executeDeployScript = function (demo) {
        console.log("Starting "+ demo.instanceName);
        $scope.clearDeploymentStatus();

        $scope.processStarted = true;

        $http.get('/api/demoSelect/startDemo', {
            params: {
                name: demo.instanceName,
                path: demo.scriptPath
            }
        }).success(function (data) {

            if (data === "Done") {

                $http.get("/api/demoSelect/startDemo/ip", {
                    params: {
                        name: demo.instanceName
                    }
                }).success(function (data) {

                    demo.url = data.replace(/\s/g, '') + ":" + demo.port
                    $scope.deploymentStatus = data.replace(/\s/g, '') + ":" + demo.port;
                    $scope.deploymentSuccess = true;
                });
            } else {
                $scope.deploymentStatus = "Demo deployed failed. Try again : " + data;
                $scope.deploymentSuccess = false;
            }
        });
```

server side route:

```
app.get("/api/demoSelect/startDemo", function (req, res, next) {

    var child;
    var demoName = req.query.name;
    var demoPath = req.query.path;
    var response = "";

    console.log("Running boot script for "+ demoName);
    child = exec(demoPath + " " + demoName,
        function (error, stdout, stderr) {

            if (error !== null) {
                console.log('exec error!: ' + stderr);
                res.send(stderr);
            } else {
                console.log(stdout);
                res.send("Done");
            }
        });

});
```

The script takes a long time to complete (a couple minutes) and I noticed that the GET request is being repeated after a couple of minutes which in turn interrupts the currently running script and starts it again. The repeat is only happening server side since none of the angular client side code is being executed again. I am noticing the get request being repeated in the gulp debug output

Is there some time of time-out value I need to adjust for long get requests to prevent them from being repeated? If so, is that something that's handled in Node or Angular?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you do paging to do incremental loads?  Sometimes if a request isnt resolved quick enough, i can see it reattempting 1-3 times before returning a server error or something similar

Comment: @Fallenreaper Would that be a reasonable solution to handle the loading of a time consuming script? How would it help?

Comment: sure why not.  Use a progress bar, which will send out incrememntal updates to the target.  That way you can in the success, every few seconds or whatever return an update on consumption.

Comment: In the return script you could do some sort of update while the return is < 1.  When it is 1, it will carry on and execute "Done"

Comment: set up a socket connection instead of ajax

Comment: @charlietfl is it the ajax taking too long to complete that is causing the repeat?

Comment: probably...a few minute is an eternity in ajax request context